# Unable to POST using Angular 7 : Header Does not work

Tags: rest, api, http, angular7

I'm currently building out an Angular 7 App, and trying to implement the following HTTP API Call Scenario:

Request for an Application Token:
https://(URL)/token

Request Type: POST

Headers:
Accept: application/json

Request Body: empty

I have a Service class in the Angular app and the code is as follows:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

The requestToken function is implemented as follows:

```
requestToken() {
 let headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');

 return this.http.post(this.configUrl + '/token', headers);
}
```

The Service is then called in one of the components in the App:-

```
getToken() {
 this.service.requestToken().subscribe( res => {
 console.log(res);
 }, error => {
   console.log(error);
 });
}
```

When I run the App, I get a 404 Not Found error in the console. I used Postman to make an API call, setting the 'Accept' header to 'application/json' and then specifying url as https://(URL)/token and I successfully get a response. But I'm unable to make it work via Angular.

Is there something else I need to do to set the header properly in Angular? Also, I have no way to check if CORS has been enabled on the API server as this is a third-party service which I'm trying to call.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you look in the network tab? What's the request that's actually getting made?

Comment: This should work. Sounds silly but check for the variable "this.configUrl", also check if you don't have a "/" in the end of it, as you already have one at "/token".

Comment: @jonrsharpe The request type is showing as POST

Comment: And the headers? One obvious issue is that a POST has a *body*, which you seem to have left out of your reckoning.

Comment: @GustavoMorais The URL is correct.. there are other functions in the service class that are making a GET request at the same URL, and all that works..

Comment: @jonrsharpe Any idea on how I can specify that the body needs to be empty ? I cannot find it in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Changed the POST call to the following:

```
requestToken() {

    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    });

    return this.http.post(this.configUrl + '/token', { body: ''}, { headers: httpHeaders });
  }
```

Had to add an empty 'body' parameter

Comment: That's not an empty body parameter, that's a body that contains an object `{"body":""}`. The second argument isn't like `options`, it *is* the body.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for your inputs.. Just getting to learn front-end development!